# VS2013 & MVC 4 -How to setup thinktecture Embedded STS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, sts-securitytokenservice, federation

I am running a project that used the local STS in VS2012 after upgrading to 2013. Now I find out that VS2013 doesn't have a builtin STS server anymore. Looking for alternatives I found this

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.EmbeddedSts/

I follow the instructions here https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/wiki/EmbeddedSts

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing I have to add a Route to my MVC routes or somekind of ignore or something to get it working right.

So has anyone got it working with MVC?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I think my configuration is mostly correct, but `http://EmbeddedSTS` is not resolved.  According to your second link, it seems to me that this should remain static for everybody's setup, but perhaps I'm misinterpreting the instructions.  I don't even know how that would work, but I have no idea what it should be changed to.

Comment: I never got it working, I just ended up using ADFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did get it working without adding a route. In addition to the help on the Thinktecture website, I followed the instructions [here](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/03/11/claims-based-authentication-in-net4-5-mvc4-with-c-external-authentication-with-ws-federation-part-2-testing-a-real-sts/).  Guessing by now you may have resolved this, if not, update the question with the symptoms of the failure.

Comment: Thanks for the link...I just ended up using ADFS.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I got this to work:

1. From VS 2013(update 2) click "New Project..."
2. Select the ASP.NET Web Application template
3. Select "MVC" and change authentication to "No Authentication" and click "OK"
4. Add references to System.IdentityModel and System.identitymodel.services
5. Edit Web.config according to [docs](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/wiki/EmbeddedSts)
6. Also add the following to Web.config:

   `<system.web>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
   </system.web>`
7. Install the ThinkTecture EmbeddedSTS package from NuGet
8. Compile and run!

Comment: Thanks but does `http://EmbeddedSTS` resolve on your machine?  If not, are you replacing the docs' stated `http://EmbeddedSTS` with something else?

Comment: It resolves without problems. Here's a copy/paste from my Web.config: `<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://EmbeddedSts" realm="https://localhost:44304/" requireHttps="true" />
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>`

Comment: Ok, yeah thanks for that confirmation.  I guess it's something particular to my environment then.